# Active directory group with members from multiple domains

Tags: active-directory

Using Windows Server 2003 active directory with multiple domains in separate forests (using two-way trusts) is there any way I can create a group on one domain that includes users from another domain?

For example:

```
CENTRAL domain users:
CENTRAL\Alice
CENTRAL\Bob

BRANCH Domain Users:
BRANCH\Carol
BRANCH\Dave
```

There is a two-way trust between BRANCH and CENTRAL, but they are not in the same forest.

Is there any way to make a group in the CENTRAL domain that includes all four users?  When I tried this I found that the membership properties of the group only let me search for users in the CENTRAL domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a DOMAIN LOCAL group, you'll be able to add the users from both domains to the one group.

Better still, add a Global/Universal group from the BRANCH domain (and the same from the CENTRAL domain) to the Domain Local group:

**CENTRAL DOMAIN** 
 SPECIAL GROUP
 CENTRAL\Alice
 CENTRAL\Bob

**BRANCH DOMAIN** 
 SPECIAL GROUP
 BRANCH\Carol
 BRANCH\dave

**CENTRAL DOMAIN**
 JOINT DOMAIN LOCAL GROUP
 CENTRAL\Special Group
 BRANCH\Special Group

That way, adding new members to the JOINT group just means adding them to the global group within their domain.

Comment: Perfect.  Somewhat counter-intuitive to use the group type named "local" to be able to include remote onjects, but exactly what I needed.

Comment: That was very clearly put, could you go to work at Microsoft writing documentation, please?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the "global" and "local" naming of groups refers to where they can be used, not what they can contain.

Also insert usual replication disclaimer about universal groups here.